# Images taken from camera roll take long time to display in ImageView android sdk

Tags: android

Images taken from camera roll take long time to display in ImageView android sdk

i am taking photo from camera and once back to my activity take long time to be displayed any one know how can i decrease this time

Comment: your image is probably too large to load quickly.

Answer (score 0):

This is because between acquire process and show process, the different frames of camera sensor was pre and post processed. Then, the picture that you see, was taken in the past time.